# What does the "version" field from itunes lookup API response refer to?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I am developing an iOS application and for some reason, I need to publish the current build with a version lower than the one which is already approved.

Suppose I currently have version 2.0.0 and build 200 approved on the AppleStore. I created another version in itunes, lower than the current one (version 1.0.0 - and surprisingly, I was alowed). After this, I changed my version and build number from Xcode accordingly (version 1.0.0 and build 100) and tried to upload but did not pass validation because the uploaded version must be greater than the approved one from store. I changed the version from Xcode to 3.0.0 and build to 300 and successfully uploaded it.

**The question is**: which version will be retrieved from itunes when the lookup API will be invoked on my app id (itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=....)? The one mentioned in the build (3.0.0) or the one in the itunes record (1.0.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of writing, **the version retrieved by the lookup API is the one set in the itunes record**.

In other words, on the example described, the returned value is 1.0.0, even though the version and build number exported with Xcode were 3.0.0 and 300 respectively.